# width and minWidth properties are deprecated in Angular

Tags: angular, deprecation-warning

I am part of a team working on an Angular project, where we update the Angular every time a new version is released.
After updating to Angular 7, the following warnings appear in the console:

> width property is deprecated, use style to define the width of the
> Dialog.
>
> minWidth property is deprecated, use style to define the minWidth of
> the Dialog.

I am not sure what does this mean. Should I avoid using `width` and `minWidth`? If the answer is a yes, what can I use instead?
Do you have any (other) suggestion that eases my work?

Comment: You are probably using some third party libraries?

Comment: Yes. We use PrimeNG.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding is the documentation on this. Probably you want `[style.width]=`, but it is impossible to tell you for sure as you haven't shared any code.

Comment: Then you have to lookup wherever you have dialogs and set the width with style, instead of just width="...

Comment: So I need to only modify the inline stylings, not the CSS files. Right?

Comment: It seems to me that yes